# shift select records in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, click, row, shift

hey guys,
i have a gridview which displays 10records per page, now i want to implement shift+click option in my gridview, when user clicks on the first row and press shift key and click on the 5th row, all the rows between 1 and 5(1 and 5 inclusive) should be selected...

can anyone suggest how should i do this in javascript.

Comment: Not sure about shift-click, but you could [use checkboxes](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Extend_GridView.aspx) for selecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it back, I found a [shift+click multiple select](http://forums.asp.net/p/1622777/4171767.aspx) solution for a gridview. All credit goes to mdv over at the asp forums.

```
var _sPreviousRow = null;
function wsCheckRange(p_oGridView, p_oControl, e) {
    var l_sCheckID = p_oControl.id;
    var l_aCheckIDParts = l_sCheckID.split(p_oGridView.id);
    var l_sCurrentRow = l_aCheckIDParts[1].split('_')[1].substring(3);

    var l_oEvent = (window.event) ? event : e;
    if (l_oEvent.shiftKey) {
        if (_sPreviousRow != null && _sPreviousRow != l_sCurrentRow) {
            var l_iFirst = 0, l_iLast = 0;
            if (parseInt(_sPreviousRow,10) > parseInt(l_sCurrentRow,10)) {
                l_iFirst = parseInt(l_sCurrentRow,10);
                l_iLast = parseInt(_sPreviousRow,10);
            }
            else {
                l_iFirst = parseInt(_sPreviousRow,10);
                l_iLast = parseInt(l_sCurrentRow,10);
            }
            for (var i = l_iFirst; i < l_iLast; i++) {
                var l_sLastRow = (i <= 9 ? '0' + i : i);
                var l_sCtrlNew = l_sCheckID.replace('ctl' + l_sCurrentRow, 'ctl' + l_sLastRow);
                var l_oCtrlNew = $get(l_sCtrlNew);
                if (l_oCtrlNew) {
                    l_oCtrlNew.checked = p_oControl.checked;
                }
            }
        }
        _sPreviousRow = null;
    }
    else {
        _sPreviousRow = l_sCurrentRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already had a look on this, can i have any simpler solution than this.

Comment: @Abbas: "simpler"? Copy-paste is too complex? I guess this prompts your definition of simple.

Comment: can you tell me how to call this function.. i mean the parameter on checkBox click event.

Comment: @Abbas: That forum post has a link to a [complete walkthrough](http://ransandeep.blogspot.com/2010/10/select-multiple-checkbox-with-shift-key.html) with demo code included.